# Uncaught Error: [Elements] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, stripe-payments, react-router-dom

I was trying to integrate the strip API key but I am not able to come up with the solution in the new react-router-dom version

here is the full error

The above error occurred in the  component:

```
at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:81119:5)
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:81052:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:79861:5)
at App (http://localhost:3000/main.79cc3231add2da1b35a8.hot-update.js:89:63)
at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:74963:5)
```

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

here is my Appjs Protected route code:

```
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

useEffect(() => {
store.dispatch(loadUser());
getStripeApiKey();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
 const stripePromise= loadStripe(stripeApiKey);
}, [stripeApiKey]);



<Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
      <Route path="/account" element={<Profile />} />
      <Route path="/me/update" element={<ProfileEdit />} />
      <Route path="/password/update" element={<UpdatePassword />} />
      <Route path="/login/shipping" element={<Shipping />} />
      <Route path="/order/confirm" element={<ConfirmOrder />} />
      {stripeApiKey && (
        <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
          <Route path="/order/payment" element={<Payment />} />
        </Elements>
      )}
</Route>
```

My protected route code

```
const ProtectedRoute = () => {
const { loading, isAuthenticated, user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
const location = useLocation();

if (isAuthenticated == false) {
return <Navigate to="/account" state={{ from: location }} />;
}
return <Outlet />;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

This issue is that you are rendering something *other than* a `Route` or `React.Fragment` inside the `Routes` component.

```
{stripeApiKey && (
  <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
    <Route path="/order/payment" element={<Payment />} />
  </Elements>
)}
```

The `Elements` component is neither and fails the invariant check.

## Solution

Refactor this into a layout route component similar to the `ProtectedRoute` component.

Example:

```
import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const StripeLayout = ({ stripeApiKey }) => {
  return stripeApiKey
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/" replace />
};
```

...

```
<Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
  <Route path="/account" element={<Profile />} />
  <Route path="/me/update" element={<ProfileEdit />} />
  <Route path="/password/update" element={<UpdatePassword />} />
  <Route path="/login/shipping" element={<Shipping />} />
  <Route path="/order/confirm" element={<ConfirmOrder />} />
  <Route element={<StripeLayout {...{ stripeApiKey }} />}>
    <Route
      path="/order/payment"
      element={(
        <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
          <Payment />
        </Elements>
      )}
    />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because of this line of code

```
 {stripeApiKey && (
        <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
          <Route path="/order/payment" element={<Payment />} />
        </Elements>
      )}
```

Only Route or React.Fragment are allowed to be children of the Routes component. But in your case if stripeApiKey turns out to be true , you are rendering Elements component which contradicts the new react router v6 rules

Like you asked in comments you want to wrap your payments method

```
<Route path="/order/payment" element={<Elements stripe={stripePromise}><Payment /></Elements} />
```

Comment: yeah, I just want to know what should i do to wrap my payment component?

Comment: Yeah you can, go inside Payment Component, wrap your jsx code with Elements, like <Elements>........</Elements>

Comment: should I wrap the react Fragments on my Payment component? and what about the getStripeKey() method?

Comment: i've edited the answer, try it out and let me know whether it works or not